# behaviour of char to ASCII code conversion

Tags: c++, character-encoding, char, ascii

I know that char can be converted to int simply assigning it to an *int* variable or by explicit casting, but I can't figure it out the behaviour of this code:

```
char tmp;

tmp = 'A' + 'A';

cout << (int) 'A' + 'A' << endl; //Prints 130

cout << (int) tmp << endl; //Prints -126

cout << tmp; //Prints �
```

According to [this](https://microsoft.github.io/makecode-csp/static/010b16b23ea4e9d9474b1d6bb4969a52/518fe/ascii-table.jpg) ASCII table I was expecting the *cout << (int) tmp;* line to print 130 just like the line before, but it prints -126 instead.
Also it doesn't print the *é* character which I find in the table, but it prints � instead.

It is because we've "landed" in the extended ASCII part of the table? Am I missing anythin else here?

Comment: (1) On your system `char` is *signed*, with the range of -128 to 127. There is no `char` with the value of 130. (2) There is no such thing as "extended ASCII". Do not ever use this popular but wildly inaccurate and misleading term. There is only one ASCII, and it is a 7-bit encoding. There are *many different* 8-bit encodings that share the first 128 character codes with ASCII. The encoding that your machine is using is not necessarily the same as my machine or her machine or theirs machine is using.

Comment: Simpler example, for your consideration: `char tmp = 130; std::cout << tmp;`

Comment: @n.m. Actually, in this case, "extended ASCII" is correct when used as part of "the extended ASCII part of the table". The three parts of the table in question are labeled "ASCII control characters", "ASCII printable characters", and "Extended ASCII characters". So these are the phrases to use when identifying parts of this specific table. (Of course, you can direct your objections to the author of the table, but please be clear about that.)

Comment: @JaMiT It is my view that "extended ASCII" is misleading and inaccurate in any context.